# 70s movie where guy could control light, even from a firefly

Tags: story-identification, movie

The guy could control light and basically use it as a weapon by shooting the photons where he wanted. He was a good guy.

The only scene I really remember is he was trapped in a van and there was a lightning bug/firefly (I think) and thus he used the light (photons) to bust open the van door and escape. I think there was a woman with him in this scene.

Comment: Sorry-- one more detail.  This was a made for TV very cheap movie.  Thanks

Comment: OK... he was trapped in the van, by the bad guys? Who wanted him for his special gift?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100765/looking-for-the-title-of-a-gold-heist-movie-involving-the-telekinetic-son-of-an (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this was ["The Man with the Power"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076358/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt). It was a TV movie intended as a pilot, but the series never got picked up. Can't find much on line, but I remember the premise was that he could use photons to move objects, so kind of a light-dependent telekinesis.