# Looking for the title of a gold heist movie involving the telekinetic son of an extraterrestrial/alien?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Some 30 years back, I saw a film about the son of an extraterrestrial who gets involved in a gold heist.

The main character does not initially know that he is the son of an extraterrestrial and that has special telekinetic powers. The film opens, I think, with him being in some train yard, his foot getting stuck in a switch with a locomotive approaching. He stops it using his powers intuitively, possibly passing out (not realizing what he actually did). I think his mother subsequently reveals his heritage to him.

He somehow gets hired as a bodyguard for someone planning a gold heist. I think they know his abilities and use him to steal a million US dollars. Actually, that is just a distraction, covering that they steal 30 million dollars from the same location (through the air, not sure on that part).

The last part I remember is some underground tunnels where the thieves set up to melt the gold. The main character is locked in there.

Does anyone know the title of this movie? Searching for things like "sci-fi gold heist extraterrestrial etc." did not reveal anything to me. I also had a hard time picking proper tags (sorry).

Comment: Could it be https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_from_Witch_Mountain?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this is not the film I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [The Man with the Power](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076358/combined), a 1977 TV movie  (that was really an unpicked pilot).

> A man whose father was an alien from another planet inherits his father's supernatural powers. He is assigned to guard a beautiful Indian princess who is on a state visit to America.

He then gets involved with a robbery. Here's the trailer, where you can see his foot getting stuck on the train tracks and him stopping that train car [try to ignore the narrator ;)]:

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to be exactly the film I remember (even though nothing of the robbery part is visible in the trailer, the rest is a perfect match). It never occurred to me it might have been a TV film or a pilot.

Comment: "He soon found out that his paranormal powers had a simple, rational explanation... **His father was an alien!!**" ROFLOL